# Извлечение переменных из dll

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте вот уже сколько мучаюсь извлечением переменных из dll

Есть  библиотека glew32.dll
В ней переменная GLEW_OK

```
[DllImport(@"glew32.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern bool glewInit();
static extern int GLEW_OK;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вряд ли она там есть - она ж константа...

Comment: Могу предложить вариант "вручную".  Импортируйте GetProcAddress, получите из неё IntPtr, и через *Interprop* вы можете прочесть int (Но проще обьявить константу)

Comment: @Qwertiy По идее мне надо значение этой константы.

Comment: @nick_n_a  По идее мне надо значение этой константы.

Comment: Я бы всё-таки поискал готовую управляемую обёртку. А вообще, что вы делаете с open gl - может игру? Посмотрите тогда на Unity. А так, ищите объявления всех констант в скачанных исходниках (воспользуйтесь поиском по файлам). Например, я нашёл онлайн: [тынц](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/blob/master/auto/src/glew_tail.h).

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Пробовал установить через References, но не смог установить. Скрин ошибки выложил.

Comment: Ваше приложение под какую версию .NET? Судя по названию используется TAO-фреймворк? Разве в его состав не входит всё необходимое?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Нет. Версия 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Переменные не "извлекаются из dll". А просто объявляются в заголовочнике (объявлении) как константа, в самом коде C#.